# Map categorical data for logistic regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run a logistic regression, predicting income based off age, num, and hours-per-week. The income column consists of either <=50K or >50. I have tried to replace the categorical data with numerics below by using the Pandas.map() function and recieved the error:
`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`. Then I tried adding the rdd function (as shown below) but get the error:
`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rdd'`

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

adult_train = pd.read_csv("C:/.../adult_training.csv")
adult_test = pd.read_csv("C:/.../adult_test.csv")

# Separate data into predictor variables, X, and target variables, y:
X = pd.DataFrame(adult_train[['age', 'hours-per-week', 'num']])
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = pd.DataFrame(adult_train[['income']]).rdd.map({'<=50K': 0, '>50K': 1}).astype(int)


logreg01 = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
```

If you could please help me be able to run the last line of code, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(adult_train[['income']]).rdd` what is this code supposed to be doing? You've passed a DataFrame to a DataFrame constructor then access `rdd`.

Comment: My guess would be `X = sm.add_constant(adult_train[['age', 'hours-per-week', 'num']])` and `y = adult_train['income'].map({'<=50K': 0, '>50K': 1})`

Comment: Map is series only. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html.